# querySelector on <select> tag with multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I want to get an array of values which is selected by `<select>` tag with *multiple* attributes by using `querySelector`, NOT jQuery.

I googled on that, but Google lists only about selecting multiple elements by using `querySelector`. In my case, I want one select element with multiple attributes.

I gave up searching on that, I just tried to code with this `<select>` tag.

```
<select id="bgmSources" className="bgmSelector" multiple="multiple"> 
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

In JavaScript, I tried as below, but nothing worked.

```js
const values = document.querySelector("#bgmSources").value;
console.log(values);
```

---

```js
const selectedOptions = document.querySelectorAll("#bgmSources option:selected");
selectedOptions.forEach(option => console.log(option));
```

Is there a way to get the array of selected options in `<select>` tag with multiple attributes?

Comment: a) "#bgmSources option:selected" is invalid, b) `selectedOptions` is not declared in code 1 ... fix the easy errors first (`#bgmSources option[selected]` is what you want for 2. to work)

Comment: Thank you for providing working code "option[selected]", and I will edit the code I tried in this post. The real code I tried is different with this code in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the children options which are `:checked`, and then get each of those selected options' values:

```js
bgmSources.onchange = () => {
  const selectedOptionVals = Array.from(
    bgmSources.querySelectorAll(':scope > option:checked'),
    ({ value }) => value
  );
  console.log(selectedOptionVals);
};
```

```html
<select id="bgmSources" className="bgmSelector" multiple="multiple"> 
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

You can't use `.value` to get a meaningful result for `multiple`, unfortunately, and you have to use `:checked`, not `:selected`.